# Combobox just file name (without extention or path) VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, path

I got the following code which is nice and all however it returns the entire path as well as name

```
        For Each s As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\ATC\BASIS\")
        combobox1.Items.Add(s)
    Next
```

What I'm after is the file name only and preferably without its extention...

UPDATE

```
            For Each s As String In GetFileNameWithoutExtension("C:\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\ATC\BASIS\")
        combobox1.Items.Add(s)
    Next
```

Comment: Use the .NET Path class, you'll want its GetFileNameWithoutExtension() method.

Comment: yeah I initially looked into this class but it dosnt seam to work for me (see update)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the Path class *inside* the loop:

```
Dim dir = "C:\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\ATC\BASIS\"
For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
    combobox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
For Each s As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\ATC\BASIS\")
    s = s.Substring(0,s.LastIndexOf("."))
    combobox1.Items.Add(s)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\softbelldata")
Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

'list the names of all files in the specified directory
For Each dra In diar1
    If dra.Extension = ".mdb" Then
        txtyear.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dra.Name))
    End If
Next
```