# How to add a list of files into a combo box?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, directory, dropdownlistfor

I'm currently working on an account system for a game using VB.Net. I was wondering how to make it so that a combo box displays a list of files within a specific directory. Here's what I mean:

When the user runs the application, I want them to see a combo box displaying a directory on their computer.

I've looked at all of the tutorials, but found NOTHING that worked.

NOTE: The combobox is in a dropdownlist style.

Comment: Is this on a web page or a Windows Forms application?  Also, you need to post some code of something you tried to give us a place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VB.NET**

```
Dim dir = "Your Path"
For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
ComboBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
Next
```

**C#**

```
dynamic dir = "Your Path";
foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir))
{
 this.comboBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
}
```

---

You can visit this post if you want more information about a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16729630/771579)

Comment: Sorry-no luck! [>:¬()]

Answer (score 1):

So many ways--perhaps the easiest to understand:

```
For Each f In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("c:\Logging\")

    MyDropDownList.Items.Add(f)

Next
```